# Error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_jdf'

Tags: pyspark

I want to perform k-fold cross validation using pyspark to finetune the parameters and I'm using pyspark.ml.
I am getting Attribute Error.

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_jdf'

I have tried initially using pyspark.mllib but was not able to succeed in performing k-fold cross validation

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.ml.classification import DecisionTreeClassifier

data=pd.read_csv("file:///SparkCourse/wdbc.csv", header=None)
type(data)
print(data)

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("SparkDecisionTree")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

# Create initial Decision Tree Model
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(labelCol="label", featuresCol="features", 
maxDepth=3)

# Train model with Training Data
dtModel = dt.fit(data)

# I expect the model to be trained but I'm getting the following error 
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_jdf'
```

**Note**: I'm able to print the data. Error is in dtModel

Comment: You will need to convert the pandas dataframe to a spark dataframe

Comment: Ill try doing that. Thank you

Comment: In case it helps someone. This error can also be thrown if you've converted the DataFrame to pandas for display after loading it. For example, by using `df.limit(5).toPandas()`.

Answer (score 19):

Convert Panadas to Spark

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

spark_dff = sqlContext.createDataFrame(panada_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

If a **metric evaluation error** you probably:

1. Transformed using Spark on test set properly, then peeked using Pandas DF.

```py
# Spark model, transformed test, converted to pandas df
predictions = model.transform(test)
predDF = predictions.toPandas()
predDF.head()
```

2. Then tried:

```
eval_acc = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(
            labelCol='Label_index',
            predictionCol='prediction',
            metricName='accuracy'
)

# Evaluate Performance
acc = eval_acc.evaluate(predDF) # Error
print(f"accuracy: {acc}")
```

I forgot **predDF is a Pandas DataFrame.**
Needed **predictions because its a Spark Dataframe.**

```
acc = eval_acc.evaluate(predictions) # Works
print(f"accuracy: {acc}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you need to use: `spark.read`, try this:

```
data = spark.read.option("header", True).csv(
 "file:///SparkCourse/wdbc.csv"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to share my experience with this error here. In my case, I had a loop and in some iterations the dataset was just a string because it was empty. When I handle the empty datsts using a 'if' my problem solved. Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).