# Dataframe Tuples

Tags: python, tuples, computer-science

I have tried creating a dataframe from a list of tuples with columns(Name, Date), but I cannot get it to process correctly. I keep receiving an error that list object has no attribute 'Dataframe'.

```
   Df= gray_goose.DataFrame(["Name", "Date"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Are 'Name', 'Date' meant to be col headings, with values for rows? Like this?

```
gray_goose = [(1, 2), (3,4)]
pd.DataFrame(gray_goose).rename(columns={0: 'Name', 1: 'Date'})

Output:

    Name    Date
0   1        2
1   3        4
```

Comment: Yes they are supposed to be the name of the columns. I am making a dataframe from tuples.

Comment: I am now receiving an error that says that the dataframe has no attribute '_jdf'.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate that error with the limited sample data. Are you perhaps using pyspark as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55604506/error-attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-jdf

Comment: I am actually using pyspark. Sorry I should have said that in the beginning.

Comment: Sorry, can't help with pyspark but hopefully the link and my answer conbines for something useful :)

Comment: I hope so too. Thank you for your help.